# Linking port audio in cc compiler

Tags: portaudio, cc

I have a program called micInput.c. It's path is `/home/pi/tromboneTuner/micInput.c` and I'm trying to use cc to compile it. The program requires port audio which has a path of `/home/pi/portaudio`. When I try to compile it with `cc micInput.c -lportaudio -L/home/pi/portaudio`, it prints this error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lportaudio
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`. Please help me figure out how to compile this correctly! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html) should fix your issue:

```
cc -o micInput.out micInput.c -L/home/pi -lportaudio
```

If your program has trouble running, make sure you are also compiling your portaudio program with whatever other library settings are needed i.e. ALSA, Jack, OSS.

Let me know if this helps out!

Comment: It's still printing out the same error. What do you mean by compiling the program with other library settings? I ran this program on a Mac without compiling any other library settings and it ran fine. Btw I'm trying to run it on a raspberry pi. Thanks for your help!